# Invoke bean method from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I would like to know how to Invoke bean method from jsp.
something like. On click of button [Hey] i would like to print "Hello world".
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead with [JSF](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html). Here's how your requirement would look like:

View (`test.xhtml`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <h:head>
        <title>JSF Hello World</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Hey" action="#{bean.hey}">
                <f:ajax render=":result" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
        <h:outputText id="result" value="#{bean.result}" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Model (`Bean.java`)

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private String result;

    public void hey() {
        result = "Hello World!";
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible ways to do this.

- [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) EL does this nicely.
- You can use [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) to invoke bean's method from just making simple javascript call, it will create ajax request to invoke bean's method at server .